# Remove space on web page if data field is null asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, null

Good morning, I am VERY new to asp.net.  I'm trying to remove the space if the field is null.  I've figured out from one of your other posts that I need to determine if the field is null and then set the visibility to false, however I'm not sure how to fit it into my page.  Here is my code:

```
<asp:Label ID="MailingAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MailingAddress") %>' />
```

Here is what I found on your site:

```
=IIF(First(Fields!AddressLine2.Value, "dsPersonData") = "",False,True)
```

I'm embarrassed to say I'm not even sure if this is asp.net c# code.  I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: The second line of code looks like Excel functions.

Comment: It's not C#, it's Visual Basic.

Comment: Well, see?  There you go.  Newbie!!!  Thank you, Claudio Redi!  I love this site!

Answer (score 4):

Try with this if you want to hide in case of null

```
<asp:Label ID="MailingAddress" runat="server" 
   Text='<%# Eval("MailingAddress") %>' 
   Visible='<%# Eval("MailingAddress") != null %>'/>
```

and this, to also take into account the empty string

```
<asp:Label ID="MailingAddress" runat="server" 
   Text='<%# Eval("MailingAddress") %>' 
   Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("MailingAddress") as string) %>'/>
```